# Disable the window resize on JFace WizardPage

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I want to disable the button maximize/minimize, below I post image to explain

[image]

this is my code :

```
public class ProjectWizardPageOne extends WizardPage {

private String platform;

public ProjectWizardPageOne(String title) {
    super(title);
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setMessage("Configure Project Name and Location");
}

@Override
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent,SWT.NONE);
    setPageComplete(false);
    setControl(container);

    Canvas leftPanel = new Canvas(container, SWT.NONE);
    leftPanel.setBackgroundImage(new Image(leftPanel.getDisplay(), this
            .getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("/icons/mypicture.png")));
    leftPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 183, 282);

    Composite rightContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    rightContainer.setBackground(new Color(null, 255, 255, 255));
    rightContainer.setBounds(181, 0, 399, 282);
}

public String getPlatform() {
    return platform;
}

public void setPlatform(String platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
}
}
```

I tried to get the Composite's Shell like this "container.getShell();" 
but I don't understand How I can set these parameters "SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.TOOL"!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a File -> New wizard or a custom wizard that is programatically launched. If it is custom, you would have to create WizardDialog and then pass Wizard instance to it. When creating WizardDialog, you would also create Shell, for which you can send the argument without SWT.RESIZE. For File -> New, since the dialog is not created by you, I dont think you can control resize option there. The resize can only be passed in the constructor of Shell.

Comment: Thanks for you replay. The Wizard is custom. As you see from my code I have created `ProjectWizardPageOne` and I call this class from here `public class NewMyProjectWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard { ProjectWizardPageOne projectWizardPageOne; public NewMyProjectWizard() { super(); setNeedsProgressMonitor(true); } public void init... public boolean performFinish... public void addPages() { projectWizardPageOne = new ProjectWizardPageOne("New My Project"); addPage(projectWizardPageOne); } }` I don't use WizardDialog.

Comment: Wizard is launched by plugin.xml
`<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
      <!-- ROOT CATEGORY -->
      <category 
        id="root_category_project" 
        name="My Project Category"> 
      </category> 
      <wizard 
          id="my_project" 
          name="My Project" 
          category="root_category_project" 
          icon="./icons/MyIcon.png" 
          class="my.project.wizards.NewMyProjectWizard"
          project="true">      
      </wizard>
 </extension>
</plugin>`

Comment: Then you wizard is part of eclipse New Wizard. You don't create the wizard dialog in this case. So, you cant disable maximize in this dialog. Simply because it will also apply to all other new wizards that the File -> New supports will have same behavior. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Yes, It makes sense. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

Controlling the `Window`/`Shell` is not the responsibility of a `WizardPage`, it can not do that. It's the responsibility of the `WizardDialog` or the code that creates it. In fact, there is no guarantee that a `Wizard` and its `WizardPage`s will even be contained in a `WizardDialog`; anything can implement the `IWizardContainer` interface to present wizards in a different way.

Comment: Thank for your reply, below the code that create Wizard Page.

`public class NewMyProjectWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard {
 ProjectWizardPageOne projectWizardPageOne;
 public NewMyProjectWizard() {
  super();
  setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
 }
 public void init...
 public boolean performFinish...

 public void addPages() {
  projectWizardPageOne = new ProjectWizardPageOne("New My Project");
  addPage(projectWizardPageOne);
 }
}`

Can you explain me where I have to modified to obtain my goal?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In case of dialogs, I have observed that I need to explicitly specify that I need min, max buttons at upper-right corner. For that I need to call the below method in a constructor:

```
setShellStyle(getShellStyle() | SWT.MAX | SWT.MIN | SWT.RESIZE);
```

Since Wizard is also a dialog, I can call the above method to reset the shellStyle not to include max, min, and other buttons (see above code). The wizard by default might be adding these buttons. But I think you can override this by recalling at the end of wizard creation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Aslam thank you for replay.
Where I have to put your code line?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class InstallerWizard extends Wizard{
...
main()
{
WizardDialog dialog = new DisableMax(shell, new InstallerWizard());
dialog.open();
}
```

}
    public class DisableMax extends WizardDialog {

```
    public DisableMax(Shell parentShell, IWizard newWizard) {
        super(parentShell, newWizard);
        setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MIN | SWT.RESIZE | getDefaultOrientation());
    }
}
```